# How to make a sticky navbar in an html & body with 100% height?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I set the height in "html" and "body" to 100% because I want the first section to fill the whole viewport, but when I do this then my navbar stops being sticky. I've tried changing the height to "min-height" but when I changed it to min-height then the first section stopped filling the whole viewport.
Is there any other way to make a section or div fills the whole viewport, or any other way to make the navbar stay sticky?

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #313131;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  padding: 0px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 4rem;
}

.nav-vertical {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
  width: 7rem;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #313131;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0px;
}
```

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">

  <!-- MAIN -->
  <section id="main" class="jumbotron-fluid background-black">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>My Name</h1>
    </div>
    <a class="scroll-down" href="#profile">
      <span><i class="fas fa-chevron-down chevron-down"></i></span>
    </a>
  </section>

  <!-- NAVBAR -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light" id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav flex-column ml-auto nav-vertical">
      <li class="nav-item nav-active">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#profile">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#experience">Experience</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I expect to:

1. Make the first section fills the whole viewport.
2. Make the navbar sticky until the end of the page.

Thank you very much.

Comment: So you're asking for a navbar that's sticky at the top of the page, and the section tag should be 100% height? Because the title implies the navbar should be 100% height

Comment: You also have a typo in your CSS: `navbar {` should be `.navbar {` or else your sticky won't be applied anyways

Comment: I turned your code into a snippet , so you can demonstrate your issue. I did not fix any of your typo. A snippet can also easily be reused by anyone answering. Welcome on SO

Comment: @JensW yes you're right, sorry my bad, I'll change the title.

Comment: @elveti it's supposed to be # (id) but somehow it seems like it prevented me from posting the thread so I deleted the # symbol. Or maybe I got it wrong, I'm sorry this is my first post and I'm still trying to get a grip.

Comment: @G-Cyr thank you for that, appreciate it.